# Element in a form

Tags: jquery

How to check if an html element [textbox, select, radiobutton etc] is in a form via Jquery?

Comment: How to… help? Help what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do

```
 obj.is('form *')
```

If you want to see if the object be in a *particular* form, you could do this:'

```
 obj.is('#formId *')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to see if there is an ancestor element of the type `form`:

```
obj.closest("form").length == 1
```

Comment: +1 for ingenuity. The answer matches the vagueness of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkboxInForm( form ){
        return ( form.find(':checkbox').size() ) ? true : false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myForm = $('#myFormId');
        if ( checkboxInForm( myForm ) ){
            // do something
        }
    });
</script>
```

Create a function for each kind of element you need to find.